# return list from linq function

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to return list of typenames from the class ApplicaitonType but i recieve error
Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' C:\Users\sharaman\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\IssueTracking\BAL_IssueTracking\AppQuery.cs 19  17  BAL_IssueTracking

Please provide your feed back on it...much appericated

public static List AppType()

{

```
        List<ApplicationType> m = new List<ApplicationType>();

        var context = new Dll_IssueTracking.IssuTrackingEntities();// Object context defined in Dll_IssuTracking DLL

        var query = from c in context.ApplicationTypes//Query to find TypeNames

                    select new { c.TypeName };

        //return query.ToList<ApplicationType>();

        m = query.ToList<ApplicationType>();//Error here

        return m;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query selects a sequence of an anonymous type:

```
select new { c.TypeName };
```

It's not clear how you're expecting to turn that anonymous type into an `ApplicationType`.

Given your data source name, I'd *expect* the method to be as simple as:

```
public static List<ApplicationType> AppType()    
{
    using (var context = new Dll_IssueTracking.IssuTrackingEntities())
    {
        return context.ApplicationTypes.ToList();
    }
}
```

In particular, it's pointless to create an instance of `List<ApplicationType>` and then ignore it, as you currently do:

```
    List<ApplicationType> m = new List<ApplicationType>();
    ...
    m = query.ToList<ApplicationType>();
    return m;
```

Why would you bother with the variable here, and why would you assign a value to it which you never use?

EDIT: From your comment:

> Actually I need to return TypeNames from ApplicaitonType class and bind to Dropdownlist through this function

That suggests your method is declared inappropriately. *Either* you can return a `List<ApplicationType>` and specify `TypeName` as the display part in the data binding, *or* you can change your method to return a `List<string>` (assuming that's the type of `TypeName`):

```
public static List<string> GetApplicationTypeNames()
{
    using (var context = new Dll_IssueTracking.IssuTrackingEntities())
    {
        return context.ApplicationTypes.Select(type => type.typeName)
                                       .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, Actually I need to return TypeNames from ApplicaitonType class and bind to Dropdownlist through this function...

Comment: @Raman: Then why have you declared your method to return a `List<ApplicationType>`? Will edit...

Comment: Hi Jon...I have one more query your help will be much appericiated In Entity Frame work I have 2 tables in the database AppType and Application. AppType has a primary key TypeID and TypeName. Application Table has AppID primarykey,AppName,TypeID foreign key from AppType Table.

I have drop down list which is bound to AppType Type Names..Now I want to return the Application Names on the basis of selected TypeNames of the Drop Downlist. I am using Linq with Entity framework.

Providing code will be much appreciated.

Thanks Raman

Comment: @Raman: That sounds like it would be best asked as a separate question, so that others can read it (and others can benefit from it in the future).

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
    public static List<ApplicationType> AppType()
    {

        var context = new Dll_IssueTracking.IssuTrackingEntities();// Object context defined in Dll_IssuTracking DLL

        var query = from c in context.ApplicationTypes//Query to find TypeNames
                    select new ApplicationType{TypeName = c.TypeName };
            return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: That won't compile - even if `TypeName` is the only property you need for `ApplicationType`, in an object initializer (not an anonymous type initializer) you need to specify the property name and value separately.

Comment: Exactly Jon i forgot property in my initializer, i'am sorry Raman